# What to pass when asked for "missing required parameters for [Route:..."

Tags: laravel

I am trying to apply a ::post function to a route with the where filter. It works without the where filter. What's missing?

This works:

```
Route::post('/actors/Chelsea_Handler', [
    'uses' => 'StarsController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
]);
```

This does NOT work but why?

```
Route::post('/{type}/Chelsea_Handler', [
    'uses' => 'StarsController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
])->where(['type' => 'actors']);
```

The function in the controller then updates some database table.

```
public function infoupdate(Request $request, $type){

    if(Auth::guest()){
        return redirect('login');
    }
    elseif(Auth::user()->id == 1){

        DB::table('stars')->where('id', $request->id)->update(['info' => 'test']);

        return back();

    }else{
        return redirect('login');
    }
  }
```

Comment: show the code where you are using the route.

Comment: post the controller code

Comment: @MohamedAthif updated the question. You think it has something to do with the controller function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried this?

```
Route::post('/{type}/Chelsea_Handler', [
    'uses' => 'StarsController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
])->where('type', 'actors');
```

Comment: This should be in comments

Comment: @arjen Bos That's not it.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have another similar route.
App is trying to find `/{type}` route.

```
Route::post('/{type}/Chelsea_Handler', [
    'uses' => 'StarsController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
])->where(['type' => 'actors']);
```

But you can have something like this in your routes file:

```
Route::post('/{anythingElse}/something', ['uses' => 'SomeController@foo']);
```

I would not recommend first segment to have curly brackets, app will use first route with this pattern.

Comment: Stanik But it is defined with the where filter type has to be "actors". And there is only one route to that exact page!

Answer (score 0):

the where in a route is meant to be a constraint in the url, and by no means as a query, such as `where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+']);`

if you need to query you can use it in the controller like below

```
$actors = Model::where('type','actors')->get();
```

Comment: That may be the case but it doesn't answer why the exact same route does not work written with the "where" filter!

Comment: does below work
Route::post('/{type}/Chelsea_Handler', [
    'uses' => 'StarsController@infoupdate',
    'as' => 'infoupdate',
]);

Comment: Nope, but I have a funky feeling that it may be because of the view/blade?

Comment: No. Its either the route or how you are trying to access the route on the browser such that you are not writing /type/ parameter in the url